# What is special about uint16_t and int64_t compared to other integer types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, types

This VSTest code compiles fine until I uncomment either of the two commented lines, in which case I get

> Error C2338   Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString(const unsigned short &). InterleavedListMode_VSTest  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\auxiliary\vs\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h   66

or

> Error C2338   Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<__int64>(const __int64 &).   InterleavedListMode_VSTest  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\auxiliary\vs\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h   66

```cpp
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
TEST_CLASS(foo) {
  TEST_METHOD(bar) {
    Assert::AreEqual((int8_t)1, (int8_t)1);
    Assert::AreEqual((uint8_t)1, (uint8_t)1);
    Assert::AreEqual((int16_t)1, (int16_t)1);
    // Assert::AreEqual((uint16_t)1, (uint16_t)1);
    Assert::AreEqual((int32_t)1, (int32_t)1);
    Assert::AreEqual((uint32_t)1, (uint32_t)1);
    // Assert::AreEqual((int64_t)1, (int64_t)1);
    Assert::AreEqual((uint64_t)1, (uint64_t)1);
  }
};
```

I checked `CppUnitTestAssert.h`, and indeed, these two types are missing. For example:

```cpp
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<bool>                  (const bool& t)                  { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<int>                   (const int& t)                   { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<long>                  (const long& t)                  { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<short>                 (const short& t)                 { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<char>                  (const char& t)                  { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<wchar_t>               (const wchar_t& t)               { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<signed char>           (const signed char& t)           { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<unsigned int>          (const unsigned int& t)          { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<unsigned long>         (const unsigned long& t)         { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<unsigned long long>    (const unsigned long long& t)    { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<unsigned char>         (const unsigned char& t)         { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<std::string>           (const std::string& t)           { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t.c_str()) ; }
template<> inline std::wstring ToString<std::wstring>          (const std::wstring& t)          { return t; }
```

It's not hard to add them, but why are they missing in the first place?

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed issue: [Closed - Not a Bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/native-c-error-still-in-vs2017-1572/262610)

*"...As per further analysis it did not seems feasible for us to define "string converter" for all types(std::uint16_t in this case), for such scenarios we expect users to convert their data into [one] of the basic type, which is supported by C++ UnitTest Framework...."*

*"Further even if we define a converter for std::uint16_t, it would fail with exception "error C2766: explicit specialization;" when compiled with flag (/Zc:wchar_t-), because we have already define a converter for wchar_t , & both uint16_t & whcar_t map to unsigned short, resulting in above error."*

Comment: So Microsoft prefers to support pre-standard code where `wchar_t` is a typedef, rather than  the typedefs present in the standard. And apparently, the fact that the compiler defines a configuration macro [_WCHAR_T_DEFINED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type?view=msvc-170) cannot be used to modify this? Amazing!